# Manipulating arms with composite geometry

Tags: manipulate

I am designing a mechanical arm and would like to manipulate it in points `{0,0}` and `{100,0}`.

But I'm finding it difficult to define the first arm as the black profile and the second arm as the red profile.

```
braço[r1_,r2_,comprimento_]:={Disk[{0,0},r1],Disk[{comprimento,0},r2],Polygon[{{0,-r1},{0,r1},{comprimento,r2},{comprimento,-r2}}]};

Graphics[{With[{x=30},{braço[25,20,100],Red,Translate[braço[20,15,50],{100,0}],Translate[{Disk[{0,0},x],White,Disk[{0,0},x/2],Rectangle[{0,-x},{x,x}]},{180,0}]}]},Axes->True]
```

How could I create this manipulation more conveniently?

[image]

Comment: More "conveniently"?  What's wrong with the one you give?  What more do you want?

Comment: I believe that to facilitate the `Manipulate function`, this geometry could be obtained in another way

Comment: I believe that the white disk and the white rectangle can be replaced by something better, obtaining the same result

Comment: "another way"?  Well sure.  But how and why would that "facilitate the `Manipulate function`"?  Just use `GraphicsGroup` and be done with it!

Comment: I have not used the software for many time, I did not remember this function

Comment: Define your graphics elements, then put them `myArm = GraphicsGroup[...]` and manipulate `myArm`.  (See examples by typing `?GraphicsGroup` and click on the link to see examples.

Answer (score 1):

I try this:

```
braço[p1_, p2_, r1_, r2_] := {Disk[p1, r1], Disk[p2, r2], 
   Polygon[{{p1[[1]], -r1}, {p1[[1]], r1}, {p2[[1]], 
      r2}, {p2[[1]], -r2}}]};
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Rotate[{braço[{0, 0}, {100, 0}, 25, 20]}, θ, {0, 0}],
   Rotate[
    Translate[{Red, 
      braço[{0, 0}, {50, 0}, 20, 15]}, {100*Cos[θ], 
      100*Sin[θ]}], α, {100*Cos[θ], 
     100*Sin[θ]}]},
   Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 200}, {-50, 150}}],
 {α, 0, π/2}, {θ, 0, π/2}]
```